# Custom `Pause` Output Batch

Tags: batch-file

Most batch users use the `pause` command, especially when debugging their programs. CMD prints on the screen when the command is used: `Press any key to continue`.

Sometimes it gets hard to remember which sections have been past when debugging.

Can this be done?

`:Part_1
(some code)
pause (echos on the screen "Part_1 Debugged"
:Part_2
(some code)
pause (echos on the screen "Part_2 Debugged"`

And so on...

Comment: You know you could simply just `Echo Part 1 Done` and then `pause` on the following line. That is essentially what Stephan's answer does in one line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo Part1 debugged &pause
```

or

```
echo Part2 debugged &pause>nul
```

or

```
set /p =Part 1 debugged
```

Note: last line needs [ENTER] instead of [Any Key]

Answer (score 2):

```
:Part_1
(some code)
set /P "=Part_1 Debugged" < NUL
pause > NUL
:Part_2
(some code)
set /P "=Part_2 Debugged" < NUL
pause > NUL
```